# How to simulate Safari 10.0?

Tags: macos, unit-testing, google-analytics, safari, user-agent-switcher

I have implemented the google analytics tracking code for a website.
I need to check if its working fine or not in safari 10.0. I cannot buy MAC now to get safari 10.0, instead finding ways to simulate safaro 10.0 with any addons?

I heard about the User agent switcher extension available in chrome/firefox from which we can simulate the browsers and its versions.

I am unable to find safari 10.0 in available user-agent switcher extensions.

Can anyone suggest me how to simulate safari 10.0 with any better extensions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to change the user-agent string, that can be done using Developer Tools for most modern browsers. Check out this [full guide from HowToGeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)

**Excerpt (For Safari)**

1. This option is available in Safari’s normally hidden Develop menu. To enable it, click Safari > Preferences. Select the “Advanced” tab and enable the “Show Develop menu in menu bar” option at the bottom of the window.
2. Click Develop > User Agent and select the user agent you want to use in the list. If the user agent you want to use isn’t shown here, select “Other” and you can provide a custom user agent. You can find extensive lists of user agents on various websites.

   - This option only applies to the current tab. Other open tabs and tabs you open in the future will use the “Default” user agent.

Comment: Thank you. I havent got safari 10 extension, but safari 9 in the user agent log. But can manage to check the recent updates for safari 10.0 in the log. Very useful answer.